# using jerkson in scala for list of lists

Tags: json, scala, jerkson

I have the following, and want to use jerkson in scala, but am having issues with this. I'm sure this is a very amateur error, but was hoping to get some help from here.

```
  scala> val orig=List("this", List("a", "b", List("c", "d")))
  orig: List[java.lang.Object] = List(this, List(a, b, List(c, d)))

 val json_ver=generate(orig)
 json_ver: String = ["this",["a","b",["c","d"]]]

 //now i want to go from json_ver back to orig list of lists
 //I've tried parse[List[Any]](json_ver)
 //parse[List[List[Any]]](json_ver)
```

All to no avail. I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

A word of warning: the original Codahale `Jerkson` has been [abandoned](https://github.com/codahale/jerkson) and there's no official build for Scala 2.10 (although there are [some](https://github.com/randhindi/jerkson) Github forks for 2.10). [`jackson-module-scala`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) (which `jerkson` wraps), on the other hand, is fully maintained and supported.

[**EDIT**] after clarifying the question.

The original data structure is using `List`s of `Any` (`List`s and `String`s). The one that's returned from the parser is `List`,  but lists inside of it are`java.util.ArrayList`.  That type is also a list, but not the same and doesn't fit in to Scala collections as natively. Among other things,  it has a different implementation of `toString`, which is why the output is different. Note that it's still a list of `Any`, just not the Scala `List`s.

One way to solve it would be just to use collection converters to convert to Scala:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
// somewhere down the line
val parsedList = parse[List[Any]](json_ver)

parsedList.foreach {
   case s: String => println("string: " + s)
   case l: util.ArrayList[Any] => doSomething(l.asScala.toList)
}

...
def doSomething(lst: List[Any]) {
   println(lst)
}
```

Another way is that if you were to use Jackson, you could configure it to use Java arrays:

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_JAVA_ARRAY_FOR_JSON_ARRAY, true)
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
mapper.readValue[List[Any]](json_ver, classOf[List[Any]])
```

Comment: sorry, what I meant was: I want to be able to convert the json_ver back to a structure that matches that of orig, in other words a list with multiple nested lists. The parse command here doesn't seem to convert all the json objects that are within json_ver.

Comment: The original data structure is not a list of lists. It's `List[Object]`, because there are both Strings ("this") and Lists in it. The one returned by the parse method is `List[Any]`. Besides that difference, I see the same elements in both.

Comment: ok, so I shouldn't expect the parse to make this List(this,List(a,b,List(c,d))? perhaps I misunderstood how parse here worked

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I don't seem to follow though on when to use this conversion. Would you mind posting a snippet of code which does this with the example provided above? That would be awesome!

Comment: I think it's best to think of a use case of what you're trying to accomplish. I updated the answer with an example of converting ArrayList to a Scala list. In general, sounds like what you really want is some class or case class to wrap your data structure, instead of just using lists.